# What kind of phrases is this? (Prepositional or Gerund)?

Tags: grammar

> After having a shower, I went to the stadium.

What kind of phrase is this - Prepositional or Gerund? And how do we know which one is it?

How do we differentiate between direct or indirect object?

Comment: It's a preposition phrase functioning as a preposed temporal adjunct. It's a PP by virtue of having the preposition "after" as head. The basic order would be "I went to the stadium after having a shower". The topic of direct vs indirect object is quite a large one; you might want to submit a separate question.

Comment: ... But you might want to read at least some of the 266 results an in-house search for "direct and indirect object" gives before you do.

Comment: Ok! Thank you BillJ and Edwin, definitely get it now, might as well look up for the Adjuncts, it's intriguing me even if it's a lesson that we might study later on! Thank you once again!!

Answer (score -1):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> It's a preposition phrase functioning as a preposed temporal adjunct. It's a PP by virtue of having the preposition "after" as head. The basic order would be "I went to the stadium after having a shower". The topic of direct vs indirect object is quite a large one; you might want to submit a separate question.